# Checking existing array have given value or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

In following code i have define empty array houseTotal, now I would like to push value inside array which is unique and not exist previously. I have use some, unique, sort filter but its pushing all the value it gets. Here is my code:

```
            let houseTotal = [];
            await rel.map((each, index) => {
                if (
                    !isEmpty(each.house_detail) ||
                    !houseTotal.some(el => el === each.house_detail._id)
                ) {
                    
                    houseTotal.push(each.house_detail._id);
                }
            });
            return houseTotal.length;
```

What I have done mistake here ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What is `rel` and why are you using `await` on it? It doesn't appear to by async at all

Comment: @jnpdx Some query that returns house detail
`let rel = await FamilyDetail.aggregate([...]); '

Comment: Then why are you calling `await` on it again in your code above?

Comment: use houseTotal.filter(el => el === each.house_detail._id).length === 0

Comment: @jnpdx its inside function, async already declare at top

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MskSatheesh its working like same as some(), pushing all value it gets.

Comment: These two conditions need to be statisfied yes, for your requirement.

Comment: @jnpdx 
`
const getLivingDetailCount = async (livingStatus, gender, ward) => {
     try {
  let rel = await FamilyDetail.aggregate([...]);
           let houseTotal = [];
            await rel.map((each, index) => {
                if (
                    !isEmpty(each.house_detail) ||
                    !houseTotal.some(el => el === each.house_detail._id)
                ) {
                    
                    houseTotal.push(each.house_detail._id);
                }
            });
            return houseTotal.length;     
     }
`
Hope this is clear for you.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense for me why to await when defining `let rel = await..` and then await again on `await rel.map`

Comment: Use if ( !isEmpty(each.house_detail) && houseTotal.filter(el => el === each.house_detail._id).length === 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `houseTotal` is to have UNIQUE values and no duplicates.. I'm going to assume "duplicates" can be `==` each other and I'll use the `Array.includes` function

```
        let houseTotal = [];
        await rel.map((each, index) => {
            if (
                !isEmpty(each.house_detail) ||
                !houseTotal.some(el => el === each.house_detail._id)
            ) {
                let detail=each.house_detail._id
                if(!houseTotal.includes(detail)){houseTotal.push(detail);}
            }
        });
        return houseTotal.length;
```

Comment: Thanks actually mistake was as you specified. It works fine with == and I fixed using toString() , both it works

Answer (score 0):

And I got the solution, it was small mistake I have made on above code, I forgot to change object id returning from mongo to string so just added toString().

```
let houseTotal = [];
        await rel.map((each, index) => {
            if (
                !isEmpty(each.house_detail) ||
                !houseTotal.some(el => el === each.house_detail._id.toString())
            ) {
                
                houseTotal.push(each.house_detail._id.toString());
            }
        });
        return houseTotal.length;
```

Comment: um, uk `toString` isn't perfect.. but still.. why did you ask for help for something so specific to you when you knew the solution :{

Comment: Nah it took me 1 day to identify that problem, silly mistake and i throw that toString from my side too.